# Tack on session support to a 'stateless' xml-rpc app

Tags: python, session

I have to create a python (twisted) application that accepts connections from clients via XML-RPC and performs operations that might require multiple steps.  The xml-rpc implementation does not have typical session support, so I need to implement it.

What I think I need is a some type of persistent object that tracks the progress of the multi-step operations, and gives the client a key that it can use to identify the operation that it initiated, to get status updates or send commands (pause/cancel etc).

To me, an appropriate model for this is "Job"; googling for "python job library" yields expected useless results.

Before I implement this, is there something existing that I can use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can have a persistent object in the server, something like :

```
from twisted.web import xmlrpc, server

class MultiStep(xmlrpc.XMLRPC):
    def __init__(self) :
        xmlrpc.XMLRPC.__init__(self)
        self.db = {}
    def getX(self, user, x):
       self.db[user] = {'x' : x}
       return 'OK'
    def getY(self, user, y):
       self.db[user]['y'] = y
       return 'OK'
    def plus(self,user) :
       return self.db[user]['x'] + self.db[user]['y']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    r = MultiStep()
    reactor.listenTCP(6666, server.Site(r))
    reactor.run()
```